# Writing a permutation group in 2 row notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I have a permutation group in $S_7$, namely: $$(12345)(137)(56)$$

How do I write this in two row notation? I am to write it as disjoint cycles and then as transpositions but I feel better working in two row notation.

Comment: I have to ask the canonical question about your permutation notation: are we to compose left-to-right or right-to-left?  It makes a difference when (as here) the cycles are not disjoint.

Comment: Hmm...It doesn't even say on the 'practice test' I am checking!

Comment: @Paze: Presumably your textbook defines which convention you're using and the test simply assumes that you're using the text's conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just compute where each element goes:

$1\mapsto3\mapsto4$

$2\mapsto3$

$3\mapsto7$

$4\mapsto5$

$5\mapsto6$

$6\mapsto5\mapsto1$

$7\mapsto1\mapsto2$.

So you have
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
4&3&7&5&6&1&2
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

First, do the product as cycles and then write it as a matrix:

$$(12345)(137)(56)=(1456)(237)\longrightarrow\binom{1234567}{4375612}$$

Answer (score -1):

It should be $$\binom{1234567}{4375612}$$
And you compose from right to left